# React-Native: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: npm, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, react-native

N.B. First time posting, so please don't hesitate to correct formatting errors, question form, etc.

I'm relatively new to react-native and but trying to build an app that makes changes to a google sheet using their API. I found a package to handle the OAuth authentication ([repo-linked-here](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth)) but it seems to be throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Module[fn]')
```

Here is most of my index.android.js:

```
...
import OAuthManager from 'react-native-oauth';

const manager = new OAuthManager('App');

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSignedIn: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    manager.configure({
      google: {
        callback_url: 'http://localhost/google',
        client_id: '*************',
        client_secret: '************'
      }
    })
    .then(resp => console.warn(resp))
    .catch(err => console.warn(err));
  }
...
```

React-native-oauth seems to indicate that if I use 'http://localhost/google' for the callback and add a few lines to the build.gradle file, then the callbacks/linking should work fine.

Any and all advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your are not calling `authorize` from `manager`. Also you can't add `then` & `catch` to `configure`:

```js
componentDidMount(){
  manager.configure({
    google: {
      callback_url: 'http://localhost/google',
      client_id: '*************',
      client_secret: '************'
   }
  });
  manager.authorize('google', {scopes: 'profile email'})
  .then(resp => console.warn(resp))
  .catch(err => console.warn(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else had this problem . 
I also had this error message and spend a lot of time to find any solution , and none of founded answers resolved my issue . 
The problem was neither configure or authorise . 
When you run (cd ios && pod install) and try to link it's asking you to overwrite pods file . Say YES . 
I found it by running app from xcode , then get error message like  :

```
framework not found DCTAuth
```

Then googling and found that it is related with pods file .
Hope this will help someone .